# Float32 Tflite quantization on input on netron is 0 < q < 255. What does this mean for my image_mean and image_std?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite

I have a float32 tflite model and when I examine the file in Netron, I see this for the input:

[image]

What does the quantization mean and based on this, what are my values for image_mean and image_std?